# iPhone SDK - UIButton Highlighted State Question

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I am having trouble with the behavior of one of my `UIButtons`. I am trying to essentially make it a **toggle button**, but I am running into the problem below.

I have the code:

```
UIButton *likeButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(horizontalOffset+buttonWidth, verticalOffset, buttonWidth, buttonHeight)];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-off.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateHighlighted];
    [likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected];
    [likeButton addTarget:self action:@selector(likeButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

which fires the method:

```
-(void)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *)sender; 
    [button setSelected:!button.selected];
}
```

The behavior I am seeing is that when I tap the button down (and highlight it), it works as expected, and the *'like-on.png'* image is used for the highlighted state, and it remains on in the *'selected'* state.

However, when I tap the button again, to toggle it off, I see a gray highlighted state when I press my finger. When I release my finger, I see the *'like-off'* image is shown as expected.

**I would like to avoid seeing the gray highlighted state when I press my finger down on the button when I go to toggle it off.** Instead I would like to make sure that the highlighted state on *toggle-off* uses the *'like-on.png'* image as specified in the code.

What's going on here? Any ideas where my code could be incorrect?

Many thanks,
Brett

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're missing the image for the selected *and* highlighted state:

```
[likeButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"like-on.png"] forState:UIControlStateSelected | UIControlStateHighlighted];
```

If you don't set it, the image of the normal state is used. From the `-[UIButton setImage:forState:]` documentation:

> In general, if a property is not specified for a state, the default is to use the UIControlStateNormal value.

If you don't want your images to be modified when they are highlighted, set:

```
likeButton.adjustsImageWhenHighlighted = NO;
```

Comment: That's exactly it! And I just learned something ;-) I didn't know that was how to specify multiple states. Many thanks!!!

Comment: What's the difference between highlighted and selected states? When does each one occur?

Comment: "Highlighted" means: user is touching it. "Selected" means the property `selected` has been set (as in: `myButton.selected = YES;`.

Answer (score 0):

I think the `selected` property of `UIButton` is meant for something different (think of the desktop UI).

It would be more consistent to change the for all states according to a `BOOL` that tracks if it is "on" or "off".

Thus,

```
-(void)likeButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    UIButton *button = (UIButton *) sender;
    liking = !liking;
    if (liking) {
        // configure the four states with "like-on" and other images
    }
    else {
        // configure the four states with "like-off"
    }
}
```

Otherwise you would use the state of a UI element to represent your program logic, which is basically flawed. The only instance where this is sort of acceptable (but not really) is a `UISwitch`.

Comment: The `selected` property is meant for exactly the thing that the poster wants to implement: a button that can be toggled.

Comment: @DarkDust: OK, but I thought you would use a `UISwitch` for that.

Comment: Often you'd use a UISwitch, yes. But think about implementing "play/pause": would you use a label+switch or a button with icons ?